# why mutableSharedFlow subscriptionCount changes when use ShareIn

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

why it changes whether use ShareIn func or not

```
val sharedf = MutableSharedFlow<Int>()

fun Flow<Int>.print() : Flow<Int> {
    return map {
          println("in print : $it")
          it
       }
    }

fun Flow<String>.printS() : Flow<Int> {
    return map {
        println("in print : $it")
        it.toInt()
    }
}

fun Flow<Int>.toNext() : Flow<Int> {
    return merge(
        filterIsInstance<Int>().print(),
        filterIsInstance<String>().printS(),
    )
}
```

when I use main func like this

```
fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> {
    launch {

        sharedf.onSubscription{
            println("subsCount : ${sharedf.subscriptionCount.value}")
        }
        .shareIn(GlobalScope, SharingStarted.Lazily)
        .toNext()
        .collect()

    }

    launch {
        for (i in 0..3){
            delay(500)
            sharedf.emit(i)
        }
    }
}
```

subsCount : 1

but if I remove ShareIn

subsCount : 2

why I have to Use ShareIn even sharedf is already MutableSharedFlow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at `toNext`, you can see that it builds 2 flows from the receiver (`this`) flow, by using twice `filterIsInstance`, and merging those 2 flows. Therefore, when you collect `someFlow.toNext()`, it will collect twice the original source flow `someFlow`.

This is why, if you don't put `shareIn` in your main method, you see 2 subscribers on `sharedf`. The `toNext().collect()` subscribes twice to the shared flow due to the implementation of `toNext()` as we've just seen.

Now, if you add `shareIn()` in the middle, you create *another, independent* shared flow. Let's call it `shared2`, and extract it to a variable to make it clearer:

```kotlin
val shared2 = sharedf.onSubscription { ... }.shareIn(GlobalScope, SharingStarted.Lazily)
shared2.toNext().collect()
```

In a way, that new shared flow `shared2` "protects" the source flow `sharedf` from collectors. When many collectors collect `shared2`, `shared2` only collects once the source flow `sharedf`.

So, even if `toNext()` collects `shared2` twice, `shared2` only collects `sharedf` once, which is why you only see 1 subscription on `sharedf` in your log.

> why I have to Use ShareIn even sharedf is already MutableSharedFlow

What makes you think you have to do that? Creating a shared flow via `shareIn` out of a flow that's already a shared flow is indeed unexpected.

---

Side note: you can use `onEach` instead of `map` in your `print` function

Comment: I saw the code block from a sample that uses flows to make MVI Architecture. 
and that code uses flow like this... 

event -> result -> state,  effect. , using flow and they all connected by ShareIn.
your answer help me a lot! thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The way `shareIn` works in very simple terms is that it launches a coroutine that runs indefinitely and collects the source flow to re-emit those values. So unlike the `map` and `merge` operators that create cold Flows that only subscribe to the source when they're collected, `shareIn` creates a Flow that immediately starts collecting from the source Flow, so it is immediately counted as a subscriber of the source flow.

The downstream `toNext()` wraps the second SharedFlow, not the first. The first one doesn't know about downstream subscribers. It is only emitting to the single SharedFlow from the `shareIn` call, so it has only one subscriber.

When you remove `shareIn`, then your top level SharedFlow is emitting to both of the subscribers that are created in your `toNext()`'s `merge()` call, so it sees two subscribers. Note that it will not see any subscribers until `collect` is called, since those are cold wrappers.